# Unable to use mongoexport on remote server

Tags: mongodb

I am new with MongoDB and I have a test account on mongogb account. I am trying to export the database I have remotely and this has given me a lot of headaches. Can someone help me out on this please?

```js
mongoexport \
    --host="myDbUser:DataBas3Pwd@mongodb://cluster0.raiy3.mongodb.net" \
    -d socialDeveloper \
    -c posts \
    --out social.json
```

When I run the code on my command line it returns the response:

```js
2021-03-01T01:13:26.240+0100    could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: cluster0.raiy3.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : dial tcp: lookup cluster0.raiy3.mongodb.net: no such host }, ] }
```

And here is where I got the connection details from on my mongoDb account

[image]

WHat do I need to change please?

Comment: It look like you are missing `mongodb+srv://`

Comment: @HanielBaez do you mean this as the host? host="myDbUser:DataBas3Pwd@mongodb+srv://cluster0.raiy3.mongodb.net  I tried it it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mongoexport 'mongodb+srv://myDbUser:DataBas3Pwd@cluster0.raiy3.mongodb.net' --db=socialDeveloper --collection=posts --out=social.json
```

Comment: Here is the error I got: error parsing command line options: too many positional arguments: [mongodb+srv://myDbUser:DataBas3Pwd@mongodb://cluster0.raiy3.mongodb.net]

Comment: It's still the same error response. I provided the correct credentials there since it's a demo database, so you can try to run the command if you care  to. Thanks

Comment: @mykoman It worked fine on my terminal. Copy it, paste on the terminal and hit 'Enter';